# Which example sentence is better?

Tags: word-usage, sentence

I'm unsure which would be the best way to write the following example sentence:

1. You asked me to call you today about X.
2. You asked me to call you about X today.

Comment: They're very similar, but why is *today* needed? There's always the possibility that the receiver reads it as fighting a paper tiger, turning their words back on them. "So I said call today, what of it?"

Comment: They're both ambiguous. The first sounds less natural.

Answer (score 1):

This is not merely a matter of opinion. It also may depend on the detail of X.

*”X today”* may be a meaningful noun phrase.

First example:

*You asked me to call you today about the First World War.*

*You asked me to call you about the First World War today.*

In both these cases the nature of X (an event completely in the past, unless the call perhaps relates to an unstated thing such as today’s historical research on the war) is such that the discussion will be about X as it was, not as it is today. It will be a general discussion, not peculiar to today.

Second example:

*You asked me to call you today about the price of tomatoes.*

The discussion may be about the generality of tomato price (in relation to demand, supply, weather etc) or it may be about today’s tomato prices.

*You asked me to call you about the price of tomatoes today.*

The discussion is likely to be about today’s tomato prices.